# python get list element according to alphabet

Tags: python, list, alphabet

I have a list of names alphabetically, like:

```
list = ['ABC', 'ACE', 'BED', 'BRT', 'CCD', ..]
```

How can I get element from each starting letter? Do I have to iterate the list one time? or Does python has some function to do it? New to python, this may be a really naive problem.

Suppose I want to get the second element from names that starts from 'A', this case I get 'ACE'.

Comment: `x for x in list if x[0] == "A"` something like that

Comment: What's the bigger picture? If you're going to use the results repeatedly, build a dictionary (or `collections.defaultdict(list)`): `d = {'A': ['ABC', 'ACE'], 'B': ['BED', 'BRT'], ...}`, then your query becomes `d['A'][1] == "ACE"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to do multiple searches, you should take the one-time hit of iterating through everything and build a dictionary (or, to make it simpler, `collections.defaultdict`):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

words = ['ABC', 'ACE', 'BED', 'BRT', 'CCD', ...]

for word in words:
    d[word[0]].append(word)
```

(Note that you shouldn't name your own variable `list`, as it shadows the built-in.)

Now you can easily query for the second word starting with `"A"`:

```
d["A"][1] == "ACE"
```

or the first two words for each letter:

```
first_two = {c: w[:2] for c, w in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) and [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> names = ['ABC', 'ACE', 'BED', 'BRT', 'CCD']
>>> next(itertools.islice((name for name in names if name.startswith('A')), 1, 2), 'no-such-name')
'ACE'

>>> names = ['ABC', 'BBD', 'BED', 'BRT', 'CCD']
>>> next(itertools.islice((name for name in names if name.startswith('A')), 1, 2), 'no-such-name')
'no-such-name'
```

Comment: that means I still have to iterate the list one time, right? my list contains like, 60,448 elements....

Comment: @JudyJiang, Yes you should iterate it. But this will stop as soon as it find the second matching element.

Comment: @JudyJiang, If you do this kind of retrieving multiple times, you'd better to make a dictionary that maps the first alphabet to matching element lists once, then query the dictionary: `d['A'][1]`

Comment: I just iterate it once and, say if I want 50 names, 2 names form 'A' and 2 from 'B', like that, 2 names each according to alphabet

Comment: @JudyJiang, See the [jonrsharpe's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22481069/2225682) that build a dictionary that maps the first character to the list. Also see a slightly different version that store at most 2 items for each alphabet: http://ideone.com/ZB1TH8

Answer (score 1):

Simply group all the elements by their first char

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

example = ['ABC', 'ACE', 'BED', 'BRT', 'CCD']


d = {g:list(values) for g, values in groupby(example, itemgetter(0))}
```

Now to get a value starting with a:

```
print d.get('A', [])
```

This is most usefull when you have a static list and will have multiple queries since as you may see, getting the 3rd item starting with 'A' is done in O(1)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
mylist = ['ABC', 'ACE', 'BED', 'BRT', 'CCD']
elements_starting_with_A = [i for i in mylist if i[0] == 'A']
>>> ['ABC', 'ACE']
second = elements_starting_with_A[1]
>>> 'ACE'
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to list comprehension as others have mentioned, lists also have a `sort()` method.

```
mylist = ['AA', 'BB', 'AB', 'CA', 'AC']
newlist = [i for i in mylist if i[0] == 'A']
newlist.sort()
newlist
>>> ['AA', 'AB', 'AC']
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to iterate over the whole list in `O(n)` :

```
(name for name in names if name.startswith('A'))
```

However you could sort the names and search in `O(log(n))` for the item which is supposed to be on the index or after (using lexicographic comparison). The module `bisect` will help you to find the bounds :

```
from bisect import bisect_left

names = ['ABC', 'ACE', 'BED', 'BRT', 'CCD']

names.sort() 

lower = bisect_left(names, 'B')
upper = bisect_left(names, chr(1+ord('B')))

print [names[i] for i in range(lower, upper)] 
# ['BED', 'BRT']
```